# How to get back sleep option in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, laptop, sleep, hibernate

I had given my laptop for a video driver software installation but after getting it back, I noticed that my sleep and hibernation options are faded in the start menu and if I close my laptop's lid, the screen turns black but my laptop still continues working. I tried searching for many answers but unfortunately could find none which would solve my problem. 
Also, if I check for driver versions and model through dxdiag, it doesn't show anything.

The results it shows:

[image]

I use 32-bit Windows 7 Ultimate.

[image: Other details]

Can anyone please help me out?

Comment: Welcome to Super User. What this feature working before? Did you ask the place you had install the driver? It is impossible for us to know what they did.

Comment: Does running the following work? "rundll32.exe powrprof.dll,SetSuspendState 0,1,0"

Comment: @CharlieRB Thanks. Yes, it was working before. I tried asking them and they just said that they downloaded a software from the internet but it didn't work. And I can't find any new driver which may have been installed.

Comment: @InterLinked What does the command actually do?

Comment: You should be able to do a [System Restore](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/restore-system-files-and-settings) to a date prior to them working on your computer.

Comment: Looks like the driver update doesn't support Suspend-to-Ram (S3) sleep mode. What graphics card are you using and why did you hand it in for an update?

Comment: @Lizzy That command should put your PC to sleep. See if that works. If it doesn't, then sleep might be disabled

Comment: @CharlieRB Thanks for the suggestion. But the problem is, that day i had installed an anti-virus and I am kind of scared that if I carry out a system Restore, then it might get uninstalled? I am not really sure since I have never did a system restore though...

Comment: @TJJ Yeah I suppose. Well, it was working previously though. I had handed it for update since they had formatted it a while ago and due to some problems, I hadn't installed the things from the driver CD. So I gave them for installing those and they said the CD was of 64-bit so they tried downloading things from internet but they didn't work as well. And then after I got my laptop back from the shop, this problem occured and the worse thing is neither of the persons remember what they downloaded.

Comment: @InterLinked Thanks. I will have to type it in the cmd.exe, right? And then I can switch my laptop on with the normal method right?

Comment: Well, if they messed it up, shouldn't they be accountable to fix it?

Comment: @TJJ That's true though. But to be honest, whatever problems I have encountered with my laptop are only due to them. So I didn't want to take any risks and thought of fixing it myself but I didn't get any solution. They say they can't fix it and only formatting might help.

Comment: That's unfortunate. I am sorry I can't help you much more here. Only thing I can suggest is to try to uninstall every driver one by one and see if that solves it. Might easily cost a day of trial and error :(

Comment: @TJJ No, it's okay. Thanks a lot for trying. I really appreciate it. :) Thank you.

Comment: @Lizzy could you [edit] your question to include the make and model of your laptop and the driver version you updated to. It will help with diagnostics.

Comment: @Lizzy Yes, although you may want to elaborate on what the normal method is for you. You dont nessecarily need to use cmd. Remember that cmd is command line, and you could the same thing by using the run dialog and pressing enter. Using cmd may provide feedback for you

Comment: @Burgi Yes,I can though. Which driver, between? The video driver is it? And I tried asking the people about the name and version of the drivers they had installed but they just said that the download didn't work and they didn't install anything and had given to another person. But that person doesn't seem to remember what he did. Neither do I remember the versions and the drivers I had before handing it to them.

Comment: @Lizzy, Yes the video driver please!

Comment: @InterLinked Oh. But if that command puts the laptop into sleep mode, then we can switched it on using normal method right?

Comment: I think so, try it and see if it works. I can't say any more than that right now

Comment: @Burgi I did edit it...Is it okay? Sorry if it's not. I don't really know and can't find any other methods to find out the driver...

Answer (score -1):

First, go to your desktop.

Right click on the desktop and you should see "Personalize" in the popup box. Click on "Personalize".

Next look at the bottom right corner of the screen and locate "Screen Saver" and click on it. The "Screen Saver Settings" box should display.

Look at the bottom left for the "Change power settings" option and click on it.

Here you can setup how your laptop's power functions will behave. I recommend you click on the "Change plan settings".

You can now configure how your power functions work "On battery" and when "Plugged in". A lot of people forget about this. Configure to your personal preference. Once done, click "Save changes" and click the back arrow at the top of the screen.

Look in the left hand column and you can change how your laptop behaves when you close the lid and other functions. Don't forget to "Save changes". Just remember how to get to this page and make changes to best suite your computing experience.